# Nested Monads Composition in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, option-type, composition, scala-cats

Here is a code example:

```
import cats.data.Reader

trait Configuration {  

  type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]

  def getValue(name: String)(map: Map[String, String]): FailFast[String] =
    map.get(name)
      .toRight(List(s"$name field not specified"))

  type PropReader[A] = Reader[Map[String, String], A]
  def propReader(name:String): PropReader[FailFast[String]] =
    Reader(map => validation.getValue(name)(map))

  type OptionalValue[A] = PropReader[FailFast[Option[A]]]
  //how to use propReader(Configuration.NEW_EVENT)
  //inside of 'event' to return 'OptionalValue':?
  def event:OptionalValue[String] = ???
}      

object Configuration extends Configuration {
  final val NEW_EVENT = "event.unique"
}
```

Cannot get it how to implement event with a composition of: `propReader(Configuration.NEW_EVENT)`

If there are more than 1 options, it would be great to consider all of them.

**UPDATE** thanks to @Travis Brown, I would implement it this way. Here is an updated implementation:

```
  import cats.instances.list._ //for monoid
  import cats.instances.either._

  type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]
  type PropReaderT[A] = ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String, String], A]
  type OptionalReaderT[A] = ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String, String], Option[A]]

  def getValue(name: String)(map: Map[String, String]): FailFast[String] =
    map.get(name).toRight(List(s"$name field not specified"))

  def propReader(name: String): PropReaderT[String] =
    ReaderT(getValue(name))

  def value2Option(value:String):Option[String] =
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) Option.empty
    else Some(value)

  def event: OptionalReaderT[String] =
    propReader(Configuration.KEY1)
      .map(result => value2Option(result))
```

The difference between this and Travis Brown's implementation: I need to see a difference between not having a key in the map (which is an error, and I need a clear error description of it) and a case when a key exists, but its value either null or empty string. So it does not work in the same way as Maps.get, which returns Option. So I cannot get rid of FailFast

Hope for someone, it will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to map into the result, promoting failures into a successful `None`:

```
import cats.data.Reader

trait Configuration {
  type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]
  type PropReader[A] = Reader[Map[String, String], A]
  type OptionalValue[A] = PropReader[FailFast[Option[A]]]

  def getValue(name: String)(map: Map[String, String]): FailFast[String] =
    map.get(name).toRight(List(s"$name field not specified"))

  def propReader(name:String): PropReader[FailFast[String]] =
    Reader(getValue(name))

  def event: OptionalValue[String] = propReader(Configuration.NEW_EVENT).map(
    result => Right(result.right.toOption)
  )
}      

object Configuration extends Configuration {
  final val NEW_EVENT = "event.unique"
}
```

I think it's worth reconsidering the model a bit, though. Any time you have a function that looks like `A => F[B]` (like a lookup in a map), you can represent it as a `ReaderT[F, A, B]`, which gives you nicer kinds of composition—instead of mapping through two layers, you only have one, for example.

The `ReaderT` approach also makes it a little nicer to change out the `F` (via `mapK`). For example, suppose as in your example you generally want to work with readers that return their values in a `FailFast` context, but you need to switch to an `Option` context occasionally. That would look like this:

```
import cats.~>
import cats.arrow.FunctionK
import cats.data.ReaderT

trait Configuration {
  type FailFast[A] = Either[List[String], A]
  type PropReader[A] = ReaderT[FailFast, Map[String, String], A]
  type OptionalReader[A] = ReaderT[Option, Map[String, String], A]

  private def eitherToOption[A](either: FailFast[A]): Option[A] =
    either.right.toOption

  def getValue(name: String)(map: Map[String, String]): FailFast[String] =
    map.get(name).toRight(List(s"$name field not specified"))

  def propReader(name: String): PropReader[String] =
    ReaderT(getValue(name))

  def event: OptionalReader[String] =
    propReader(Configuration.NEW_EVENT).mapK(FunctionK.lift(eitherToOption))
}      

object Configuration extends Configuration {
  final val NEW_EVENT = "event.unique"
}
```

The `OptionalReader` here isn't exactly the same as your `OptionalValue`, since it doesn't include the `FailFast` layer, but that layer is redundant in your code, since missing values are represented in the `Option` layer, so the `OptionReader` approach is likely to be a better fit.

Comment: thank you! As usual your answer is complete and clear. Nevertheless it takes time to get used to it, cause it is another way of thinking at all:) Why are there thousands of courses that are similar by their nature related to Java, Scala, other languages, other topics, but so few about these FP approaches?

Comment: some notes: I need to see differences between not having a key in the map, and when its value is null or empty string. I have updated my question, based on your answer. Hope someone will find it also useful.